# Passing a bigger file from VF to Apex Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, limits, blob

I created a page that passes a file from the VF to the Controller. It's working fine, except when the file is bigger I hit the blob limit in the controller.

What I do:

1. On the front end I convert the attached file to a string.
2. Pass that string to a variable in the controller.
3. Then do blob.valueOf() to convert the string to a blob. Then I assign that blob to the attachment.Body.

I was following this article: http://manojjena20.blogspot.com/2015/11/apexinputfile-can-not-be-used-in.html

Now my issue is when I try to attach a bigger file. I get this kind of error: `String length exceeds maximum: 6000000` on the line that convers the string to a blob.

What can I do to assure that bigger files can be converted and uploaded as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options here:

1 - Ask Salesforce to increase the file limit in your organization (they can set it up to 25mb [according to Jeff Douglas](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/28/uploading-an-attachment-using-visualforce-and-a-custom-controller/)).

2 - Rework your code to use the Ajax Toolkit (JavaScript) to upload the file, so you can upload larger files. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/loading-files-greater-than-5m-using-vf-page) can clarify that, I believe.

3 - Use a third-party application connected to Salesforce to receive the files, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720978/salesforce-upload-large-files-upto-250gb-through-visualforce-to-external-server).

Comment: Thank you. Now I experience an issue on the front end too getting a `Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded.` How is that possible?

Comment: When you save the file, are you setting the file's variable to null? You must do so when your attachment exceeds the view state's size. For example: it is ok if you upload a 200kb file. But if you don't set the variable - to which the file was bound - to null when the page is rerendered, then Salesforce will try to cache the file in the view state (and it will exceed the limit).

Comment: Do you mean the variable in the controller?

Comment: Yes, the variable you use to assign the file.

Comment: The problem is that I store the attachments in a List of attachments and insert them all at once when the user clicks on the save button. What can I do in this case?

Comment: I think you can solve that by using an internal list that won't be accessible in the controller (see how to use the Transient keyword https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm). Using this you can store the attachments in this variable (that won't be loaded in the view state) and have a different list with a custom wrapper class to hold the attachments' information (like name, size, but not the body) and then show this instead of the list of attachments.