# Not able to create ContentDocumentLink from sforce ajax

Tags: content, contentversion, contentdocument, ajax-toolkit

I have followed [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/35212/22234) to create a content version from vf page using sforce ajax and it is working fine.

To link the uploaded content to one of my custom object I added the below code;

```
var result1 = sforce.connection.retrieve("id,ContentDocumentId", "ContentVersion", [results[0].id]);
console.log('1---'+result1[0].ContentDocumentId);
var contentDocumentLink          = new sforce.SObject('ContentDocumentLink');
contentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = result1[0].ContentDocumentId;
contentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId ='a0F2800000D7cXF';
contentDocumentLink.ShareType = 'I';
results = sforce.connection.create([contentDocumentLink]);
console.log('2---'+results);
```

But every time it throws exception.

Log:

> 2---{errors:{fields:'LinkedEntityId', message:'You cannot create a link for this type of entity through the api: Linked Entity ID', statusCode:'FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION', }, id:null, success:'false', }

Is there a way to create ContentDocumentLink from javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find my below code:  -

```
   <apex:page >
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CreatecontentDocumentLink()
    {          
            var contentDocumentLink = new sforce.SObject('ContentDocumentLink');//Initialize the contentDocumentLink
            contentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = '06990000001zDCnAAM'; //Document Id
            contentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId ='00690000002FBX2';//Linked Object Id , in My case it is opportunity record Id
            contentDocumentLink.ShareType = 'V'; //Required. The permission granted to the user of the shared file in a library. This is determined by the 
                                                    permission the user already has in the library. This field is available in API version 25.0 and later.
                                                    V
                                                    Viewer premission. The user can explicitly view but not edit the shared file.
                                                    C
                                                    Collaborator permission. The user can explicitly view and edit the shared file.
                                                    I
                                                    Inferred permission. The user’s permission is determined by the related record. For shares with a library, this is defined by the permissions the user has in that library.
            results = sforce.connection.create([contentDocumentLink]);
            alert('results---------'+results);
    }              
</script>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandLink styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" value="New Case" id="clink" onclick="CreatecontentDocumentLink(); return false;"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The code is running perfectly.
Just check below things : -
1. version of API
2. then check share Type.
3. After that the permission on object record.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the problem was with the js versions. I made it same as the page version, it started working.